# Migrated shoper won't fully work - htaccess issue?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm getting some 404 errors on transferred site from another server.

Previously site was running under domain.com, now it's transferred to domain.com/subdir/

Not all links are rewritten, some shows domain.com/subdir/rewritten_path which is proper but some links shows domain.com/rewritten_path which leads to 404 error.

A word of advice?

Using Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 SVN/1.9.3

.htaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^webapi/net-soap.*$ api.php?objects=1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/soap.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/json.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/rest.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/front.*$ api.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Rewriting won't fix the content the site serves. You need to reconfigure it and/or make changes to the code and any static/DB content so all links a user receives have the correct path.